# If $A$ is a ring containing $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and $a \in A$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$, can we say $a^p$ is also a root of $g(x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

> Let $p$ be a prime, and let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the finite field with $p$ elements. If $A$ is a ring containing $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and $a \in A$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, can we say $a^p$ is also a root of $g(x)$?

I don't know much about algebra, so when I was solving this problem, I found that if $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $a^p$ is also a root, but when $a$ is not in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, I have no idea how to prove it. I would really appreciate if you can share with me your ideas.

Comment: What is $\Bbb Z_p$? This notation is overloaded for many rings, which is why I ask.

Comment: Also, it is considered good practice to keep the body self-contained which is why I have copied the question to the body.

Comment: What I mean is that $\mathbb{Z_p}$ refers to the ring that contains all the reminders mod p.

Comment: In that case, $a^p = a$ for all $a \in \Bbb Z_p$, so the fact about $\Bbb Z_p$ is not really saying much.

Comment: Yes, then if $a$ is not in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, is $a^p$ also a root?

Comment: No, that is not the case anymore.

Comment: Would you please give me a counter example please? Since I don't really know what kind of ring containing $\mathbb{Z_p}$, I cannot imagine which $a\in A$ that is not in $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is a counter example. Thanks you!

Comment: I have added an answer which gives some examples. The issue is that you mention that you don't know much about algebra, which makes it a bit difficult for me to think of a ring that you may be familiar with.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, then $\mathbb Z_p$ is actually a field of characteristic $p$, and $a$ is in a finite extension of $\mathbb Z_p$. In this case, $a^p$ is also a root of $g(x)$.

Comment: @CHENRK Are there any counter examples if $g(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z_p}[x]$? Sorry if it a silly question.

Comment: @fioaq Is $p$ a prime? If this is the case, then the answer is always yes. Otherwise, we can easily find a counterexample since $a^p\ne a$ for some $a\in\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: I shall take back my earlier comment of "No, that is not the case anymore." I had misread the question. I have also now updated my answer accordingly, thanks to @CHENRK. I have also kept my earlier answer after mentioning what I misread it as. Please make a note of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments, you are using $\Bbb Z_p$ to mean $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Also, I'm going to be assuming that $p$ is a prime. Otherwise, the result is not true even when $A = \Bbb Z_p$. (I am going to assume that all my rings are commutative.)

---

> If $A$ is a ring containing $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $a \in A$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, can we say $a^p$ is also a root of $g(x)$?

The answer to this question is "Yes".

The key is [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) which says that $a^p = a$ for all $a \in \Bbb Z_p$.

The other key is the fact that if $A$ is a ring that contains $\Bbb Z_p$ as a subring, then we have $p \cdot a = 0$ for all $a \in A$. Thus, we have the nice identity:

$$(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)^p = a_1^p + \cdots + a_n^p$$

for all $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$.

Using the above two, we see that if $a \in A$ is any element and $g(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$ is any polynomial, then we have

\begin{align} 
g(a^p) &= a_0 + a_1a^p + \cdots + a_n(a^n)^p \\ 
&= (a_0 + a_1a + \cdots + a_n a^n)^p = g(a)^p.
\end{align}

In particular, $a^p$ is a root of $g(x)$ whenever $a$ is a root of $g(x)$.

---

There's a follow-up one can ask:

> If $A$ is a ring containing $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $a \in A$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) \in \color{red}{A}[x]$, can we say $a^p$ is also a root of $g(x)$?

The answer to this question is "No". One "easy" example is the following: Take $A = \Bbb Z_p[t]$. This is the polynomial ring in the variable $t$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Then, consider the polynomial $g(x) = x - t \in A[x]$. Then, $t$ is a root of $g(x)$ but $t^p$ is not, since $t^p \neq t$.

---

If the above example is a bit too abstract to comprehend, here is what we essentially need: Take any ring $A$ containing $\Bbb Z_p$ such that there exists some $a \in A$ with $a^p \neq a$. Then, you can take the polynomial $g(x) \in A[x]$. It will have $a$ as a root but not $a^p$.

Plenty of such rings do exist, by the way. For example, you can take any field of characteristic $p$ which has more than $p$ elements. Another example was the ring $\Bbb Z_p[t]$ which I gave above.

Comment: Thanks you! I have limited knowledge in Abstract Algebra. Would you please recommend some books that cover the topics like this so that I can learn from?

Comment: I think $g(x)$ should be in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ rather than $A[x]$.

Comment: @fioaq: Dummit and Foote have a nice book called "Abstract Algebra". Also, note CHENRK's comment. I didn't read the question properly, so my answer at the moment is not correct.

Comment: Thank you @CHENRK: I have updated it now.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I have a stupid question. If $a\in \mathbb{Z_p}$, then there is Fermat's little theorem, but if a is not in $\mathbb{Z_p}$, can we still use the theorem to prove the claim?

Comment: @fioaq: I'm not sure I get your question. If $g(x) \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$, then the coefficients of $g(x)$ satisfy $a_i^p = a_i$ by Fermat's little theorem. I don't require $a^p = a$ to get $g(a^p) = g(a)^p$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. I misunderstood your explanation. Thanks again!